# array.includes returning false where as searched name is in array

Tags: javascript

If `var c = familyArray.includes("Bart");` it will return `false`  but if `var c = familyArray.includes("Homer");` it will return `true`

I want it to be true in the case of `Bart` as well because it is also included in the array.

Below is my array:

```js
var familyArray = ["Marge", "Homer", ["Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie"]];
var a = familyArray.indexOf("Bart");
var b = familyArray[2][0];
var c = familyArray.includes("Bart");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Your array has an array inside of it; there are *two* arrays, not just one.

Comment: how do i search array inside array

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that you have a multi-dimensional array, and array `includes` will not search the inner array. Thus, you need to flatten your array before searching it. Here I have used `Infinity` as a parameter in the case that your array has more dimensions than just 2:

```js
var familyArray = ["Marge", "Homer", ["Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie"]];
var c = familyArray.flat(Infinity).includes("Bart");

console.log(c); // true;
```

See browser support for `.flat()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility). If you need better browser support you can use an alternative approach found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#reduce_and_concat)

Comment: TIL you can use `Infinity` with `.flat()`, I've used recursive functions in the past. Thanks :D

Comment: `flat()` has poor browser support (no IE, no Edge) and is trivial to implement so it's better to just polyfill

Answer (score 2):

You are using nested arrays, you can use `.flat` before hand:

```js
familyArray.flat().includes('Bart')
```

Comment: Note that `.flat()` isn't implemented in all browsers, but MDN has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternative) (sort-of)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching in the inner array. You can do like this.

```js
var familyArray = ["Marge", "Homer", ["Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie"]];

console.log(familyArray[2].includes("Bart"));
```

Comment: the probleme with this is that you require to know the index of the inner array and you are not searching in the parent array.

Such as:
`console.log(familyArray[2].includes("Marge"))`
Would return false

Comment: in that case we have to verify if inner item is array if so we can check. flat() method wont work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```js
var c = familyArray.flat(1).includes("Bart");
```

Answer (score 0):

try `flat` method for this

```js
var familyArray = ["Marge", "Homer", ["Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie"]];
var familyArrayFlatten = familyArray.flat();
var a = familyArrayFlatten.indexOf("Bart");
var b = familyArrayFlatten[2][0];
var c = familyArrayFlatten.includes("Bart");



console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```